# vert.x non blocking & threading model

Tags: vert.x

I am just starting to learn about vert.x and am interested in how thing work still...
I was wondering:

when a reactive non blocking verticle off loads work to a blocking vertical which runs on a worker thread.

1.what does the event loop thread, that off loaded the work, does in the mean time? take another event from the loop?

2. when the a result is returned, does the same event loop continues execution? or a different one?
3. what are the answers to 1 & 2 in the case that a non blocking verticle off loads work to another non blockiong vertical (like a reactive sql client).

I feel I am missing some basic stuff regarding how things actually work.
thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your 3 questions:

1. Yes, the event loop thread continues handling events, if any, of the standard verticle
2. A result returned is an event that the same event loop will handle
3. The answers to 1. and 2. are the same in the case that the standard verticle offloads work to another standard verticle.